# Program needed to display graph of tab delimited file on web in real time

Tags: file, graph

What I need is a method to display a graph of data from a tab delimited file uploaded to a website. Once the file is uploaded the program will convert the data to a graph or the graph be generated locally and sent to website, but it needs to be automated and in realtime.

Thanks,

Antone

Comment: I think we need more information.  What does the data look like?  What kind of graph are you displaying?  Are you using server side technology (ASP.NET, Java) or client side technology?

Comment: Just looking for a program can take TDF and display it on the web. I am doing it in excel, I just want to automate it.

Thanks,

Antone

Comment: I do not care which platform does the job. The simler the better for now.

Comment: Antone, if it's a poll question, it should be made community wiki. I've voted to close as in present form your question  makes little sense. Automated and real time is more of a buzzwords than any useful description of a system.

Comment: As ususal I beg to differ the question makes little sense. Automated means in the context of the question used refers to having the graph displayed on the web site with out user intervention. Real-time means the data is continously updated and has not bearing of the data being uploaded to the website. They are not buzz words they are both independent of each other in meaning and in use.

Thanks,

Antone

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by a polling question. If this is question needs to be moved to another area then that is fine with me. Otherwise please do not comment on area of computer science that you do not fully understand. What I am asking is very simple thing to do, I am sure it has been done many times over now with complete tools sets and libraries. As before with my quesitons I am writing them to people that understand what I am asking not to people looking for reputation points.

Thanks,

Antone

Comment: Seems to me people on here are for more interested in criticizing than helping resolve issues. 

Thanks,

Antone

Comment: While the question may make perfect sense to you, it has most people confused, which is why you don't really have any sort of answer even starting.  Instead of looking at it as people being critical, maybe you should take people at face value and understand they are confused by your question.

Comment: Good point, and i have gotten this before from comments. Nevertheless the question is pretty simple to anyone with a  background with statistical packages knows what a CSV file is or Tab delimited file is and how in 10 seconds you can take that file to excel an create a grahical representation of the data.  There is no need to know what platform ASP, CFM, Java, .NET or anything else.

Thanks,

Antone

Comment: Maybe also the issue is a programming issue, where people believe I am looking for code snippets- not true. I am looking for a complete solution which will probably be a web graphing utility program or Python, Perl script with and added graphing library or 3rd party tools.

Thanks,

Antone

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather broad.

The answers to these questions usually depend upon what sort of programming framework you will be using for your website.  For example, PHP has some native libraries to generate graphs based on submitted data in multiple formats.  But that may not be what you are looking for and using something like dojo or ExtJS might be better.  Or if you are a Java/JSP person, then there are lots of frameworks that can handle this.  Of course .NET might be better.  I am sure the Python and Ruby folks have their own thoughts as well and then of course there is Delphi.

Comment: thanks - for the reply, any solution I can work with the script does not matter. OK so PHP sounds fine to me. I hate java way to slow but I can deal with it, but like the PHP idea better. Can you give me specifics. Read my next comment and I will tell you more.

Comment: So, If I use PHP, then the script will create the graph from the TDF locally and upload the file to the website?